# Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state" at the commented line

Tags: c#, snmp

I created a c# SNMP application using the [SNMP library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12993/SNMP-library?fid=265779&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=1#xx0xx).

But then I get an error *"**Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state"*** at the commented line.

```
try
        {
            UdpAddress udp = new UdpAddress(args[1]); //error occur at this line
            SnmpVersion ver = SnmpVersion.SNMPv1;
            //some other snmp codes
        }
```

this codes declare the args variable:

```
public Hashtable getValues(SNMPObject[] SNMPObjects)
    {

        int nbrArgs = 5 + 2 * SNMPObjects.Length;
        string[] args = new string[nbrArgs];
        args[0] = "get";
        args[1] = this.getIPAddress();
        args[2] = "-Dl0"; //don't make debug
        args[3] = "-c" + this.getCommunityRead(); //community read
        args[4] = "-C" + this.getCommunityWrite(); //community write
        int i = 5;
        foreach (SNMPObject mySNMPObject in SNMPObjects)
        {
            args[i] = "-o";
            args[i + 1] = mySNMPObject.getOID();
            i = i + 2;
        }

        //lancer la requête
        Hashtable htResult = Manager.makeOrder(args);
        return htResult;
    }
```

when I debug by line, the args[] passed as:

```
[0] = "get"  
[1] = "10.0.0.120"  
[2] = "-Dl0"  
[3] = "-cpublic"  
[4] = "-Cpublic"  
[5] = "-o"  
[6] = "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0"  
[7] = "-o"  
[8] = "1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.1"
```

Comment: Problem can be on args. Can you post the code where you declare args variable?

Comment: @Phx already edit my question, correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Try this, UdpAddress udp = new UdpAddress("10.0.0.120"); shows the same error?

Comment: @Phx yes,I have tried. Still have the same error.

Comment: The problem is on the DLL. The constructor probably it's not ok (or the property that is using)

Comment: Check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12993/SNMP-library?msg=4361325#xx4361325xx

Comment: The library is dead and not maintained (the code base is hard to maintain too). If you do want to do SNMP development seriously, switch to other frameworks, #SNMP or SNMP#NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible reasons can be infinite loop somewhere in UdpAddress constructor. Could you show what's in UdpAddress constructor?

Comment: the UdpAddress constructor is a library .dll files use by the SNMP library. Is it possible to get what is it in the .dll file?correct me if im wrong.

Comment: if it's not your class then you can get the code from decompiling software like .NET Reflector or JustDecompile

Comment: Contact the author(s) of the lib, maybe?